# Use a RedirectResponse object of CodeIgniter4 with JS

Tags: javascript, forms, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have a project running with CodeIgniter 4, and I tried to use JS to send a POST request to a controller. This controller sends a RedirectResponse in response, but with JS, I wasn't able to use it to open a new window with the information.

Here is a part of my controller :

```
public function attemptCreate(): RedirectResponse
    {
        $rules = [
            'slug'            => 'required|max_length[128]',
            'audio_file'      => 'uploaded[audio_file]|ext_in[audio_file,mp3,m4a]',
            'cover'           => 'is_image[cover]|ext_in[cover,jpg,jpeg,png]|min_dims[cover,1400,1400]|is_image_ratio[cover,1,1]',
            'transcript_file' => 'ext_in[transcript,srt]|permit_empty',
            'chapters_file'   => 'ext_in[chapters,json]|permit_empty',
        ];

        if ($this->podcast->type === 'serial') {
            $rules['episode_number'] = 'required';
        }

        if (! $this->validate($rules)) {
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->withInput()
                ->with('errors', $this->validator->getErrors());
        }

        ...
```

And here is my JS script :

```
try {
                const response = await fetch("<?= route_to('episode-create', $podcast->id) ?>", {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: formData,
                    redirect: 'follow'
                });

                if (response.ok) {
                    const responseData = await response.json();
                    console.log(responseData);

                    // Try to use responseData
                } else {
                    console.error('Erreur de requête:', response.status, response.statusText);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
```

I tried to open the body of the server's response, but it didn't work very well (some CSS files were missing, and the JS script didn't work). Due to CSRF security, I wasn't allowed to resend a POST request with the same form. To escape this problem, I tried to reload my page after sending the form, but all the information entered in the form was reset.

I also attempted to use the form without using JS, but I want to change an input before sending it, and I didn't find another way to do that without using JS.

Comment: I would return a string url (instead of the redirect response) and redirect with that in your JS. Probably the easiest bet.

Comment: I tried to do that, but it didn't work well because my form was reset, and CodeIgniter attempted to display errors on the new page. However, these errors didn't appear when I went directly through the URL.